# Parse: Remove user when session ends?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I was wondering if it were possible to remove a user completely from the database if their session ends? Maybe in sign up, I can check if there is a session for the username the person is using and if there isn't, it deletes the previous user and registers a new one?

How do I check if there is a current session for a certain username?

UPDATE:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friends"];
    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        for (Friends *currentFriend in objects) {
            [currentFriend deleteInBackground];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: I don't have code yet because I don't know how to check if a session has a certain username. Would I make a query of the Session class for the user's objectId, then if there is no results, find the user with that objectId and remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:
1. [Recommended] Use a anonymous user to begin with, Reference can be found [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-anonymous-users).
2. In AppDelegate.m - applicationWillTerminate: method, you can do

```
[user deleteInBackground];
[PFUser logOut];
```

This will delete your logged in user permanently, locally and from remotely.

To

> check if a session has a certain username

, all you need to do is:

```
PFUser user = [PFUser currentUser];
if ([user.objectId isEqualToString:"myTargetUserId"]) {
    NSLog("Target user exists");
}
```

Comment: Can I set values to anonymous users? For instance can an anonymous user create a username, and if they delete the app the session is deleted therefore, the username to the anonymous user is deleted?

Comment: I also tried adding in this, but it doesn't delete it from Parse (update in code above). That code also doesn't delete the sessions.

Comment: To delete user from Parse, you can do it locally with OC, using the '[user deleteInBackground];'. To delete session, just do '[PFUser logOut]'; that should remove the currentUser from you local session. To check session, you can check if '[PFUser currentUser];' returns nil.